# Alert shows empty message if called from task

Tags: task, javafx-8, alert

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
  public Void call() {
    try {
      // my task code
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
  }
};
task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
  Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "task success", ButtonType.OK);
      alert.showAndWait();
    }
  });
});
```

In my above code i am trying to display alert message from success part of task.

I have deployed the application in a remote machine and accessing the same using remote desktop connection.

when i keep my remote desktop connection window minimised i get the alert message empty. (Yes i see the message when RDC window is open)

when i focus on parent container(stage) it refreshes and shows the correct message or just alt + tab few times also works. Tried various solutions to set modality, init stage, some vm args etc nothing seems to work.

any idea why this problem is? I understand task is a seperate thread and hence i have used platform.runlater? Have i done anything wrong? any alternative solutions?

Task runs on new thread as its performing a heavy operation.

Comment: *"I understand task is a seperate thread and hence i have used platform.runlater ?"* Depends on how you run it. You could theoretically use `Task.run` to run the task on the application thread. You don't need to use `Platform.runLater` when handling the `onSucceeded` event though, whether you run the task on a seperate thread or not, since `Task` makes sure the handler runs on the application thread.

Comment: First of all thanks for quick response. Secondly "whether you run the task on a seperate thread or not" yes its run on a seperate thread. My task is a heavy operation and hence i prefer to keep application thread free from it.

Comment: ITS AN OPEN BUG WHICH WONT BE FIXED : 

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8118805